# Pathos Processes Not Dying with Main

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I have a main script that passes a function and a list of strings to a (Pathos) `ProcessPool.map` function. The problem I am having is that when I run the process from command line and try to `Ctrl + C` out of the main thread I am unable to end the process and then when I close the terminal and examine processes on the machine I can see all of the python processes that the `ProcessPool` spun off are still alive and don't appear able to exit. Am I misusing the library?

```
accounts = ['THIS', 'ACCT', 'HAS', '$$$']

executor = ProcessPool()

executor.map(testScript.run_for_account, accounts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I wasn't closing or terminating the process pool. See [source](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/pathos/multiprocessing.py) here for details but like the basic python multiprocessing pool you need to call either `terminate()` or `close()`